# Split edge ring with edge loops with fixed absolute distance from borders

Tags: python, scripting, edges

How can I create edge loops that have a fixed or absolute distance from the borders instead of a percentage factor?

[image]
Or any suggestions what method to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to set absolute values say, $0.2m$, you can enable and use the addon *Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools*.

[image]

Once you have the addon enabled, you can use `bpy.ops.object.mesh_edge_length_set` to set a fixed distance from the borders. First create 2 [Loop Cuts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Then select the 3 edges at a time and run a simple script I have prepared at the bottom. This may be tedious at first but this is just to give you an idea. You can further refine your script to automate all of that.

[image]

Here's the script. Just change variable `new_length` to another fixed or absolute value from border.

```
import bpy
import math

new_length = 0.2 # change this to specify distance from border

obj = bpy.context.active_object

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

v = obj.data.vertices
total_length = sum((v[e.vertices[0]].co - v[e.vertices[1]].co).length for e in obj.data.edges if e.select)

bpy.ops.mesh.select_nth()

bpy.ops.object.mesh_edge_length_set(target_length=total_length - 2 * new_length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Start adding a loop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then press <kbd>E</kbd>, then press <kbd>F</kbd> if you need to switch side.

[image]

Comment: he said with fixed distance, i think he wants to be able to set the length to a certain absolute value, not in percentage.

Comment: Yes, as Harry McKenzie said I need a slide on the absolute value (10mm for example). Your Edge Slide uses Factor method and I firstly looked at this method but didnt get how it calculate factor value, what edge uses to calculate length to percentage slide...